# javascript puppeteer next page problem when i evaluate

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

**trying to navigate all pagination , get deals links , and console.log them.but problem is: it wont click the next page since page.click function not works inside page.evaluate() need to write them with js and not works**

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 20,
    defaultViewport: null,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://www.amazon.com.tr/deals?ref_=nav_cs_gb", {
    waitUntil: "networkidle2",
  });

  //await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid="grid-deals-container"]');

  const siktir = await page.evaluate(() => {
    var while_status = true;
    var list = [];
    while (while_status) {
      setTimeout(() => {}, 5000);
      let sayi = document.querySelector('[data-testid="grid-deals-container"]')
        .children.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < sayi; i++) {
        list.push(
          document
            .querySelector('[data-testid="grid-deals-container"]')
            .children.item(i)
            .children.item(0)
            .children.item(0)
            .children.item(0).href
        );
      }
      if (document.querySelector(".a-last a") === null) {
        while_status = false;
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector(".a-last a").click();
      }, 3000);
    }
    return list;
  });
  console.log(siktir);
  //await page.click(".a-last a",{delay:3000});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

**A lil help would be good**

Comment: Hiya, can you try and be clearer about what the exact problem is?

Comment: its not goes to next page.Chrome stays with main page link

Answer (score 0):

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    slowMo: 20,
    defaultViewport: null,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://www.amazon.com.tr/deals?ref_=nav_cs_gb", {
    waitUntil: "networkidle2",
  });

  const numberOfDivs = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelector("li.a-disabled:nth-child(6)").textContent;
  });
  console.log(numberOfDivs);
  var sayfa = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfDivs; i++) {
    await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
    sayfa++;
    console.log(sayfa);
    var lale = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let list = [];
      var sayi = document.querySelector('[data-testid="grid-deals-container"]')
        .children.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < sayi; i++) {
        list.push(
          document
            .querySelector('[data-testid="grid-deals-container"]')
            .children.item(i)
            .children.item(0)
            .children.item(0)
            .children.item(0).href
        );
      }
      return list;
    });
    console.log(lale);
    await page.click(".a-last a");
  }
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Still need to get fixed but at least i can get the links of the products.